# Monthly numbers of customers and their (all time) purchase frequencies

Tags: sql, frequency, amazon-athena

I am trying to find the customer count (monthly) and their purchase frequencies (all-time) between March 2020-March 2021. Since the frequency will be the entire time frequency of that month's customers instead of their monthly frequency, I'm thinking of writing a query where I change the date to find the outcome for each month.

For example, when I run the query for January 2021, I want to get the number of customers who purchased in January 2021 and their average frequency until February 2021 (which means including January).

Basically, I want to get something like the following,

| customer_count | alltime_frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 100.000 | 1.8 |

I have tried the following query,

```
SELECT count(distinct t.customer_id) AS customer_count,
       count (distinct t.orderid)/count(distinct t.customer_id) AS frequency
FROM "order_user" t
WHERE  t.order_date>= TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01 00:00:00'
       AND t.order_date< TIMESTAMP'2020-02-01 00:00:00'
```

but this gives me the frequency of only that month, not the all-time frequency.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I'm not sure what you really want to calculate.

Comment: Probably easier to split into two different queries. One to count distinct the customer ids, and the other to count the frequency of their orders based on their customer ids.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if I understand your question correctly without sample data, but you could try something like this? There are other possibilities with window functions to calculate this on the fly for all months, but I'm not sure that's what you need.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN  t.order_date>= TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
         THEN t.customer_id END) AS customer_count,
  COUNT(distinct t.orderid)/COUNT(DISTINCT t.customer_id) AS frequency
FROM order_user t
WHERE t.order_date  < TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01 00:00:00'
AND   t.order_date >= TIMESTAMP'2020-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, based on your answer i tried the following; 
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t.order_date>= TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01 00:00:00' and t.order_date< TIMESTAMP'2021-02-01 00:00:00' THEN
    t.cust_id END) AS customer_count, COUNT(distinct t.orderid)/COUNT(DISTINCT t.cust_id) AS frequency
FROM order_user  t `  
this is good at giving the number of customers who have purchased that month but unfortunately it calculates the all-time frequency of all customers, not the frequency of customers who have purchased that month.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
with cte as (select customerid, count(distinct orderid) as order_count
from mytable
group by 1
having count_if(order_date between period_start and period_end) >0)
select  sum(order_count)*1./count(*) from cte
```

explanation: the cte counts orders for each client for  clients who placed at least an order in the selected time period. Then you just sum all orders and count clients.

Comment: depending on how you store data, the `distinct` might be unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments and answers here, i came up with this

```
   SELECT count(distinct t.customer_id) AS customer_count, 
   1.00 * count (distinct t.orderid)/count(distinct t.customer_id) AS frequency
   FROM mytable t1
   WHERE t1.customer_id IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT t.customer_id
     FROM mytable t
     WHERE t.order_date>= TIMESTAMP'2021-01-01 00:00:00'
     AND t.order_date< TIMESTAMP'2021-02-01 00:00:00')
   AND t1.createdate< TIMESTAMP'2021-02-01 00:00:00'
```